# Есть ли OR в Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Интересует вопрос - есть ли в Sphinx оператор `OR` в таком контексте. Или как это можно заменить.

`SELECT * FROM bids WHERE field1 = 111 OR field2 = 222 ORDER BY date_published DESC LIMIT 0, 15 OPTION max_matches = 1;`

`AND` можно точно, но на `OR` ругается.

Comment: `OR is not supported yet but will be in the future.` [Нет](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/sphinxql-select.html).

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написали в комментариях OR в секции WHERE использовать нельзя.
Но под селектом никто не запрещает:
`SELECT *,(field1 = 111 OR field2 = 222) as fieldFlag FROM bids WHERE fieldFlag=1 ORDER BY date_published DESC LIMIT 0, 15 OPTION max_matches = 1;`